# URL Definitions

Tags: facebook, url

When coding URLs on my canvas page I am currently using the following:

```
<a href="script.php">Link</a>
```

This then links the user to www.mydomain.com/myapp/script.php, but in doing this the getUser function seems to return 0 (even though getUser returns the correct user ID from the canvas page displaying the link).

Or should I be aiming to code the URL in the following way:

```
<a href="apps.facebook.com/myapp/script.php">Link</a>
```

If I input this URL in to the browser directly then getUser returns the correct value. However, if I link to it from the canvas page in this manner the page seemingly comes up blank?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP SDK can only extract data from the signed_request posted to it on the initial page load (the POST) - from there on it is up to you to persist that information, eg by storing it in session.

The reason why linking to the canvas app url works is that this ends up doing a full post, but this is unnecessarily expensive, has high latency, and is, well... unnecessary, and not the right thing.

So, in the initial POST, store the id in the session, and use that on subsequent page loads.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question now is why is the session not being persisted if I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK? So sticking with the example above, the user comes to the app and views the canvas page and the user id is (for example) 12345. The user then clicks on the script.php link (there is no form being posted here) at which point the user id is now 0. I don't understand why, as script.php creates the Facebook object again, which is calling session_start(), and getUser should persist this should it not?

Comment: Re-recognizing the user via the session will only work, if passing of the session-id has worked – and since you are in an iframe, you browser might not accept the cookie that’s set to store the session-id. Keyword for your search: _third party cookies problem_